# If someone "stole" my Facebook App ID, what damage could they do?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a Facebook App ID and set the site URL to "localhost" so that after authenticating (via client-side JavaScript), I am redirected to my local machine while I'm developing the app.

I'm curious to know if there's any risk in this setup, specifically, what would happen if my App ID were stolen. It seems like the worst thing that could happen is that someone else could use my App ID with their own locally-hosted app and cause my app to exceed its Graph API usage quota, etc. Are there other risks?

Comment: Update: I haven't gotten an authoritative answer on the risks here, but someone on the Facebook dev forums suggested playing it safe and putting the app in 'sandbox' mode while the Site URL is localhost. http://goo.gl/fPb19

Answer (score 3):

You should not worry about.

Facebook App ID can be easily retrieved from any site that uses facebook JS SDK.

What you should worry about - is your `app secret key`

Comment: And normally the "Site URL" restriction prevents it from being used by anyone else. But in this case the site url is localhost. So, for example, you could use *my* App ID with *your* locally-hosted app. What bad things could you do with it?

Comment: @Clint Harris: how exactly could I use it if I don't know app secret?

Comment: If you just use client-side authentication (i.e., JavaScript only) you don't need to use the secret key. See the "Client-side flow" section in the Authentication docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: @Clint Harris: I know about that. But that doesn't allow to retrieve anything that is not available for public.

Comment: @zerkms But believe it would exhaust the quota?

Comment: @pinkpanther to be honest I don't remember what quotas were for facebook api 10 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I also think this is risky, not for the localhost issue ( you can change it to other thing, like mylocal.develop, map it in the /etc/hosts, and authorize that in Facebook, as I did. It works ), but for the IP spoofing or domain spoofing by header forgery ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing )

Not sure if it can be avoided forcing ssl mode in Facebook or something like that.