# Facebook app security - what if someone uses my AppId?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If someone “stole” my Facebook App ID, what damage could they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603917/if-someone-stole-my-facebook-app-id-what-damage-could-they-do)

From this post: [If someone "stole" my Facebook App ID, what damage could they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603917/if-someone-stole-my-facebook-app-id-what-damage-could-they-do) seems like no damage can be done if someone steal my appId and connect with it to facebook APIs and publish bad things on other people's wall, right?

I've been thinking if I could be responsible in that case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases App Id can be taken from javascript sources. The only thing that you should be worry about is App Secret.

Comment: so it's not a problem whether someone uses my AppId as long as I keep my app's Secret Key hidden, right?

Comment: without the app secret it has no use at all - it's just a unique id for your app.

Comment: Right. App Id could be recevied from oauth url, for example this is Farmvile app id - 102452128776